# Why won't any users be added to my database?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a full stack application for a personal project. I am using SQLite, SQLAlchemy, and flask for the backend side of things. I made a model in models.py called "User", which of course represents the users who sign up and use the application. For some reason, every time I enter a flask shell and try to add a new user to the database using db.session.add() and db.session.commit(), nothing gets entered into the database at all!

I think the problem may be with how I've set up the users password to be hashed with bcrpyt. Below is my config.py file showing all the configuration I did for the backend

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///app.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.json.compact = False

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention={"fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",})
db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)
db.init_app(app)

api = Api(app)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

load_dotenv()

app.secret_key = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
```

and below this is the "User" model in models.py. Reminder that I used sqlalchemy for the database models.

```
from config import db, bcrypt
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class User(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    _password_hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)

    def get_password_hash(self):
        return self._password_hash
    
    def set_password_hash(self, newPassword):
        byteObject = newPassword.encode("utf-8")
        newHash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(byteObject)
        hashAsString = newHash.decode("utf-8")
        self._password_hash = hashAsString

    _password_hash = property(get_password_hash, set_password_hash)
        


    
    def authenticate(self, passedString):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self._password_hash, passedString.encode("utf-8"))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'ID: {self.id}, Username: {self.username}'
```

Any help is IMMENSELY appreciated.

Tried editing password hashing functionality but still came to the error of it not adding users to the database

Comment: When initializing `Migrate` the `db` instance should already be initialized so you should move `db.init(app)` above `Migrate(app, db)`. Not sure though if that solves the problem. You generated an Migrate Skript with `flask db migrate` and updated the database with `flask db upgrade` before entering the shell session?

Comment: Check whether you have more than one app.db file in your app's directories.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a little different than how I learned to do this. You probably need to import sqlite3, for starters. I have never used the metadata portion of your code but you should pass your app to the db setup:

```
import sqlite3
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I'm not saying it can't be done but I have never seen the password hashing done inside the database model. This model tells the app what to expect inside the database. I would suggest moving the password hashing to an add user route and committing the hash to the database from there. I used WTForms for this and created a UserForm. Hopefully you can modify this to your specific use case.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField, ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo

# User form class
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    username = StringField('Username:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    color = StringField('Favorite Color:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    pw_hash = PasswordField('Password:', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('pw_hash2', message='Passwords must match!')])
    pw_hash2 = PasswordField('Confirm Password:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')    

# Add user page route
@app.route('/add_user', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_user():
  name = None
  form = UserForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    if user is None:
      # Hash the password
      hashed_pw = generate_password_hash(form.pw_hash.data, method='pbkdf2', salt_length=16)
      user = Users(username=form.username.data, name=form.name.data, email=form.email.data, color=form.color.data, pw_hash=hashed_pw)
      db.session.add(user)
      db.session.commit()
    name = form.name.data
    # clear the form
    form.username.data = ''
    form.name.data = ''
    form.email.data = ''
    form.color.data = ''
    form.pw_hash.data = ''
    flash("User Added Successfully")
  our_users = Users.query.order_by(Users.date_added)
  return render_template('add_user.html', form=form, name=name, our_users=our_users)
```